# xlsxwriter error - Trying to write SQL output to excel sheet

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I am trying to write the output of a SQL query to an excel using XLSXwriter module.

```
dwh_cur.execute("""select count (*) from sales where created_at = current_date - 1""")
sales = dwh_cur.fetchall()
worksheet1.write('A1', 'Sale ID')

row = 1
col = 0

for elm1 in sales:
    worksheet1.write(row, col, elm1)
    row += 1
```

Get an error :

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple'
```

Given below is the data I am trying to write to the excel file

```
Sale_ID
1001
1002
1003
1004
1005
```

Could anyone assist as to where am I going wrong. Thanks..

Comment: The error is quite clear. Have you tried printing elm1 in the loop and seeing what the output is?

Comment: Print out `elm1` and you will see what the problem is. You're expecting it to be a number, but it isn't, it is a 1-tuple. When you fetch rows from the database, you get back one tuple per row. Even if there is only one column in the query.

Comment: "Could anyone assist as to where am I going wrong" well actually posting here before trying to debug this by yourself IS already wrong. The error message is rather clear,  and tracing the code (using print statements or the step debugger) would have solved the problem in a few minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dwh_cur.fetchall()` is returning a list of tuples, probably:

```
[(1001,), (1002,)]
```

With this in mind, you should write the cell as follows:

```
dwh_cur.execute("""select count (*) from sales where created_at = current_date - 1""")
sales = dwh_cur.fetchall()
worksheet1.write('A1', 'Sale ID')

row = 1
col = 0

for elm1 in sales:
    worksheet1.write(row, col, elm1[0])
    row += 1
```

You could also make use of Python's `enumerate()` function to automatically give you a row number:

```
dwh_cur.execute("""select count (*) from sales where created_at = current_date - 1""")
sales = dwh_cur.fetchall()
worksheet1.write('A1', 'Sale ID')

col = 0

for row, elm1 in enumerate(sales, start=1):
    worksheet1.write(row, col, elm1[0])
```

If multiple items are being returned, i.e. for a second column, you could add them as follows:

```
for row, elm1 in enumerate(sales, start=1):
    worksheet1.write(row, col, elm1[0])
    worksheet1.write(row, col+1, elm1[1])
```